# how to set a loading state for react js with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i'm using redux and i want to show an loading state for my app whenever my app is catching data from api and whenever i have an data of null in my reducers 
i've tried this but i got no loading text

```
    if (this.props.isSignedIn === true) {
      return <div
        style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
        <Link to='/streams/new' className='ui button primary'>
          create new stream
      </Link>
      </div>
    }
    if (this.props.isSignedIn === false) {
      return <div style={{ fontSize: '30px' }}>Not a user? sign in now, it's free </div>
    }
    if (this.props.isSignedIn ===null) {
      <div>loading...</div>
    }
  }
```

here is connect and `mapstatetoprops` function

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    streams: Object.values(state.streams),
    userId: state.auth.userId,
    isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchStreams }
)(StreamList);
```

and here is reducer

```
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT } from '../actions/types';

const INTIAL_STATE = {
  isSignedIn: null,
  userId: null
};

export default (state = INTIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGN_IN:
      return { ...state, isSignedIn: true, userId: action.payload };
    case SIGN_OUT:
      return { ...state, isSignedIn: false, userId: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

here is actions

```
export const signIn = userId => {
  return {
    type: SIGN_IN,
    payload: userId
  };
};

export const signOut = () => {
  return {
    type: SIGN_OUT
  };
};
```

## NOTE:

in cases true and false works fine except for null

Comment: do you set the ```isSignedIn``` variable to ```null``` at all?

Comment: yes it is null at first and changes over time

Comment: also post your redux actions and reducer to help you better

Comment: i updated my question, by the way it works fine in true and false cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is done with setting 'loading' property on store and adding an additional action such as 'SIGN_INIT'

So your reducer will look like this:

```js
const INTIAL_STATE = {
  isSignedIn: null,
  loading: false,
  userId: null
};


export default (state = INTIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGN_INIT:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case SIGN_IN:
      return { ...state, isSignedIn: true, loading: false, userId: action.payload };
    case SIGN_OUT:
      return { ...state, isSignedIn: false, loading: false, userId: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

So when you try to sign in or out, first you dispatch SIGN_INIT which sets 'loading' to true. Whenever request is finished SIGN_IN\SIGN_OUT actions will have your 'loading' prop updated in store and component will be notified that loading is finished.

Comment: i only defined a loading value and set its default to true ,whenever actions invoke i change the value to false ,does it have different?